# How to collaborate on one git commit in Gerrit?

Tags: git, gerrit

How can **one commit** be worked on by multiple people in Gerrit? There are really two scenarios in mind.

**Scenario A - simple collaboration**

1. Developer A creates and pushes the commit to Gerrit on the master branch.
2. Developer B checks out the change following Gerrit's instructions, resulting in a detached head, but with Developer A's changes.
3. Developer B makes some changes.

What does Developer B do now in order to make their changes in the detached head amended to Developer A's commit in the master branch?

**Scenario B -- complex collaboration**

1. Developer A creates and pushes the commit to Gerrit on the master branch.
2. Developer B checks out the change following Gerrit's instructions, resulting in a detached head, but with Developer A's changes.
3. Developer B branches from this detached head twice (Fork Y and Fork Z), to make multiple WIPs.
4. Developer B works on Fork Y until it's ready to be merged with Developer A's single commit in master.

How does Developer B get their Fork Y work into the single commit on master?

Answer (score 1):

I *believe* I have a solution that works:

1. [pull patchset from Gerritt]
2. Git checkout -b foo
3. [make & commit changes to foo branch]
4. Git checkout master
5. git merge —squash —allow-unrelated-histories foo
6. [fix any merge conflicts]
7. Git commit —amend
8. Git branch -D foo